# How do I see if each number within one array is found squared within another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

> Given two arrays a and b write a function comp(a, b) (compSame(a, b)
> in Clojure) that checks whether the two arrays have the "same"
> elements, with the same multiplicities. "Same" means, here, that the
> elements in b are the elements in a squared, regardless of the order.
>
> **Examples**
>
> Valid arrays
>
> ```
> a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]  
> b = [121, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361]
> ```
>
> `comp(a, b)` returns true because in b 121 is the square of 11, 14641
> is the square of 121, 20736 the square of 144, 361 the square of 19,
> 25921 the square of 161, and so on.

To start I just wanted to go through each item and test whether the squared version was present in the other array. This is my code:

```js
function comp(array1, array2){
  return array2.every((item)=>{
    let a = array1.indexOf((item ** 2));
    if(a >=0){
      return true;
    } else{
      return false;
    }
  })


}


console.log(comp([121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11], [121, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361]));
```

This example is of course supposed to return true. My code appears pretty basic, so I am not sure why it doesn't work. Additionally if I put an empty array for the second array it returns false.

Comment: What should be the answer for `a = [11,11],b = [121]`? I suppose it should be `false` because it does have `121`  but it appears only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `every` and `includes`, this can be written with a simple one-liner :

```js
const a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]
const b = [121, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361]

const comp = (a, b) => a.length === b.length && a.every(value => b.includes(value ** 2))

console.log(comp(a, b))
```

It's pretty explicit, this function checks if both array have the same length, and if every value of `a` squared is included in `b`.

Comment: `includes()` makes it O(n^2).

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for `array2` and check each product of `array1`.

```js
function comp(array1, array2) {
    const set2 = new Set(array2);
    return array1.every(v => set2.has(v * v));
}

console.log(comp([121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11], [121, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361]));
```

Comment: The question asks for _the same multiplicities_. `Set` loses this information.

Answer (score 1):

Using every and a set to remove duplicates

```js
a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]  
b = [121, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361]

function compare(a,b){
 a=[...new Set(a)]
 b=new Set(b)
 
 return a.every(x=>b.has(x*x))
   
}

console.log(compare(a,b))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost good for the test case. You just have the arrays swapped inside:

```
function comp(array1, array2){
  return array1.every((item)=>{
    let a = array2.indexOf((item ** 2));
    if(a >=0){
      return true;
    } else{
      return false;
    }
  })
}
```

Although if I understood correctly this will return true even if the arrays have different lengths, or if the second array have elements that are not multiplicity of an element in the first one, as long as the first one has some multiplicity in the second one:

```
console.log(comp([2,4,4,2], [4,16]));
// -> true
console.log(comp([2,4], [4,16, 536]));
// -> true
```

So, to be faithful to the premise, and be *a lot* more efficient avoiding indexOf or includes:

```
function comp2(A, B){
  if(A.length != B.lengt) return false;
  
  A.sort((a, b) => a-b);
  B.sort((a, b) => a-b);
  
  return A.every((a, i)=>{
    const b = B[i];
    if(a ** 2 == b){
      return true;
    } else{
      return false;
    }
  })
}

console.log(comp2([2,4,4,2], [4,16]));
// -> false
console.log(comp2([2,4], [4,16, 536]));
// -> false
```

Playground: https://jsfiddle.net/alotropico/9ukmL5g3/13/